# Jasmine - Check if service method within a controller method was called

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine

I started testing my ionic/angularjs app with Jasmine one day ago. I'm not sure if I totally misunderstood the idea of testing, but I want to test if a service method within a controller method was called and how the controller reacts to anything returned.

The controller function I'd like to test looks like this:

```
$scope.init = function() {
    DataService.fetchValues('dataprotection').then(function (result) {
        $scope.dataprotection = result;
    }, function (failure) {
        $scope.dataprotection = 'No dataprotection available';
    });
};
```

My Test should look like this:

```
describe('DataprotectionController', function () {
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, DataService) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('DataprotectionCtrl', {
            '$scope': scope
        });

        dataService = DataService;
    }));

    it('Should init dataprotection on startup', function () {
        // call init function in controller
        scope.init();
        //check if dataservice.fetchValues have been called with 'dataprotection' as parameter
        expect(dataService, 'fetchValues').toHaveBeenCalledWith('dataprotection');
        //calling fetchValues should init scope.dataprotection variable
        expect(scope.dataprotection).toBeDefined(); 
    });
});
```

Of course this is not working. Errorlogs tell me to create a spy object. So I did...

```
spyOn(dataService, 'fetchValues').andCallThrough();
```

Didn't help so I'm calling

```
dataService.fetchValues('dataprotection');
```

right after "scope.init();". First expect passes.

The thing I really don't understand is: why am I creating a spy object for the dataService fetchValues() method and then call it with a parameter and check if it was called with the given parameter? I don't want to call it manually, I want to check if dataService.fetchValues('dataprotection') was called inside the scope.init() function of DataprotectionController.

Sorry, if this is a really stupid question, but I'm literally stuck...
Thanks for your help!

Comment: What version of Jasmine are you using? 1.3 or 2.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*The following syntaxes are for Jasmine 2.0, so if you are using Jasmine 1.3 you need to make some small changes.*

First of all you need to inject the `DataService` into the controller:

```
var $scope,
    DataService,
    $q;

beforeEach(module('myApp'));

beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, _DataService_, _$q_) {

  $scope = $rootScope.$new();
  DataService = _DataService_;

  controller = $controller('DataprotectionCtrl', {
    '$scope': $scope,
    'DataService': DataService
  });

  $q = _$q_;
}));
```

Note that if you use `and.callThrough()` the spy will delegate the function call to the real `fetchValues` implementation, unless you have replaced it with a mocked function yourself.

You can instead use `and.callFake` to return a promise:

```
spyOn(DataService, 'fetchValues').and.callFake(function(input) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve('mock');
    return deferred.promise;
});
```

Otherwise the following code in your controller wouldn't return anything:

```
DataService.fetchValues('dataprotection')
```

Which means it would try to do the following on `undefined`:

```
.then(function(result) { ...
```

When using `ngMock` you need to synchronously maintain the flow of the tests, so after calling `init` you need to manually trigger a digest to get the promise to resolve:

```
$scope.init();

$scope.$digest();
```

And finally the syntax for verifying that the service function was called is:

```
expect(DataService.fetchValues).toHaveBeenCalledWith('dataprotection');
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Pslme1Ve1M1E6hbm1J6D?p=preview